# How to monitor Spring-data-redis pool metrics?

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

I want to monitor the pool metrics in Spring-data-redis. JedisConnectionFactory's pool is private. How can I get it? I search google but I cannot find good way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Though Redis client use connection pool, most of time client use one connection to get/set of the data. Also, redis is single threaded application.  You may not need connection pool information.